# How to write a linear map as a matrix with respect to a given canonical basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am asked to write a linear map as a matrix with respect to a given canonical basis. The basis is

$b = \left \{ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\
0 \end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\
1 \end{bmatrix} \right \} $.

The map is given by $\phi: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$; $(x,y) \rightarrow (x+y, x-y)$.

I know that $\phi$ as a matrix is $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Any help would be nice. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Study the answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/608674/52893

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column vectors of the matrix of $\phi$ are the images of the basis vectors under $\phi$. For example the image of the first basis vector is $\phi\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1+0\\ 1-0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$, which is the first column of the matrix of $\phi$.

Comment: Ah yes, very good. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Your'e welcome.